# Call Javascript after a href method

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created on MVC View and i get call required data on that view load. Also i add one Ajax call when view is load and bind my graph detail using chart.js method.
Now i have multiple links on that view and when i click on particular link it should bind detail and graph as well.

```
<a class=" p-head" onclick="javascript:LoadGraph()" href="@Url.Action("MachineSeverityP/", "Machine", new { @id = PItems.MachineID, @AreaID = PItems.AreaID })">@PItems.MachineName</a>
```

This is my a href where i call my controller method and ajax method as well.

My requirement

I want to call my controller method first and then want to call AJAX call as i use id from controller method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain your requirement more detailed? Are you trying to open a page by clicking the anchor, and you want to fire jquery ajax after the page loads?

Comment: When you put together the requirements, are you gonna pay for an answer? :)

Comment: It's request-response. The client makes a request and the server responds, end of transaction.

Comment: @ramiramilu yes you are right after clicking the anchor and page load i want to fire Jquery ajax. Is that possible.?

Comment: Then you have to write that jquery in `document.ready` of the opened page.